# Unpermitted parameters on belong_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, strong-parameters, belongs-to

I have an association as follows:

```
class Membership < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

and

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :memberships
end
```

Now I have a form to create a new membership. Within this form I also want to input new user information. I am using SimpleForm. My basic structure is as follows (using HAML not erb files):

```
= simple_form_for @membership  do |f|
...
   = simple_fields_for @user do |uf|
      .field= uf.input :firstname, label: 'First Name', required: true
...
= f.button :submit, 'Submit'
```

`@user` here is an instance variable set in the new action on the Memberships controller (`@user = User.new`). I would like to keep it this way so I can use SimpleForm's inference on user attributes (i.e., `uf.input :firstname` maps to the `firstname` attribute on the `User` model)
Now given this background, when I hit submit the goal is to create a new membership and a new user associated to that membership. How can I permit parameters for the single associated user?

At the moment I have:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def membership_params
   params.require(:membership).permit(users_attributes: [:id, :firstname] )
end
```

Here is the request:

```
Started POST "/memberships" for ::1 at 2018-10-15 15:08:42 -0600
Processing by MembershipsController#create as HTML
   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"omitted==", "membership"=>{"user"=>{"firstname"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Unpermitted parameter: :user
Unpermitted parameter: :user
Unpermitted parameter: :user
##################### {}
No template found for MembershipsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 264ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have no template rendering on purpose for now.

Given this parameter structure:

```
"membership"=>{"user"=>{"firstname"=>""}}
```

I have also tried the following for permitted parameters:

```
params.require(:membership).permit(user_attributes: [:id, :firstname] )
params.require(:membership).permit(user: [:id, :firstname] )
```

Notice I the `################ {}`. This is a manual puts I have in the create action. `puts '################ ' + membership_params.to_json`. As you can see it yields nothing. Also why do I get the 'Unpermitted parameters' logged three times?

**UPDATE 1** controller code:

```
class MembershipsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  # GET
  def new
    @membership_plans = Plan.active.sort_by { |plan| plan.sequence }
    @user = @membership.build_user
  end

  # POST
  def create
    debug_puts(membership_params.to_json)
  end

  private
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def membership_params
    params.require(:membership).permit(user_attributes: [:id, :firstname, :lastname] )
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

I don't deem this as an acceptable answer (which is why I'm not formally "answering" my question), but what I have decided to do is invert my form. The relationship is still the same among Memberships and Users, but the parent form is for a User:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
...
   = f.simple_fields_for :memberships_attributes do |mf|
   ...
```

This means I put `accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership` on the User model (a has_many association with memberships) and all the rendering and param permitting is done within the Users Controller

```
# new action in users_controller.rb
def new
   @membership_plans = Plan.active.sort_by { |plan| plan.sequence }
   @user = User.new
   @user.build_membership
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(memberships_attributes: [:id, :field1, :field2] )
end
```

Comment: Forgot to include this important piece of info: I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user` on the Membership model.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **build** the `user` for `membership` in the `new` action of `memberships_controller`.

```
def new
  @membership = Membership.new
  @user = @membership.build_user
end
```

and make sure you have `user_attributes` not `users_attributes` in the `membership_params`

```
params.require(:membership).permit(user_attributes: [:id, :firstname] )
```

**Update:**

There is one more important piece of code which need to be fixed.

This

```
= simple_fields_for @user do |uf|
```

should be

```
= f.simple_fields_for @user do |uf|
```

Comment: This is a useful piece of information. Building the associated model is better than creating a new one and associating manually, but I still still the `Unpermitted parameter: :user` message and print out `membership_params` still yields nothing.

Comment: Shoot, I wish that was the culprit. I just copied it down wrong in my original post! I have been using `f.simple_fields_for`

Comment: @mtprogrammer Ok, I would be eager to see the controller code. Specially full `new` and `create` methods. Can you update the question with those?

Comment: @mtprogrammer Is that what you have? I dont see the definition of `@membership`

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` will create @membership. Having `@membership = Membership.new` still yields the same results with an unpermitted parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181968/discussion-between-pavan-and-mtprogrammer).